# How many teams can be made from 11 people?

Tags: permutations, combinations

The question asks this:

Five places exist on a team. $11$ total people. $6$ come from district A, $4$ from district B and $1$ from district C.

How many different groups of five are there?
How many different groups of five are there if each team must contain at least one person from each district?

Question 1 is easy, it is simply $\binom{11}5$, but I do not know how to do the second question.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding up the following:

- The number of groups with $3A+1B+1C$, which is $\binom63\cdot\binom41\cdot\binom11=80$
- The number of groups with $2A+2B+1C$, which is $\binom62\cdot\binom42\cdot\binom11=90$
- The number of groups with $1A+3B+1C$, which is $\binom61\cdot\binom43\cdot\binom11=24$

Will give you $80+90+24=194$ such groups.

Comment: @user2764359: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 7):

The player from C must always be on the team. We have $\binom{10}{4}$ possibilities how to choose the rest of the players. There are $\binom{6}{4}$ of them that would not contain a player from B and $\binom{4}{4}$ that would not contain a player from A. So the result is 
$\binom{10}{4} - \binom{6}{4} - \binom{4}{4}.$

Comment: Right. Maybe for good form you should add that it is of course impossible to neither have any player from A nor any player from B, so that you are not subtracting any possibilities twice (which would then need correction by inclusion-exclusion).